# Salesforce Marketing Cloud SOAP API - how to create an AccountUser without the 'Add to From Name dropdown' being checked

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am able to successfully create a new Account User in the account. One thing I notice is that every new create results in the user's Reply Email Address showing up in the Sendable Dropdown list due to the user's property being checked for "Add to From Name dropdown". I'd like to see if there is a property on the Create call that be set to False or No, but I haven't found one in the WSDL or documentation.

ex. of my working AccountUser call:

```
   <soap:Body>
      <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options>
            <SaveOptions>
               <SaveOption>
                  <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
                  <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
               </SaveOption>
            </SaveOptions>
         </Options>
         <Objects xsi:type="AccountUser">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <Client>
               <ID>MID</ID>
            </Client>
            <UserID>username</UserID>
            <Password>xxxxxxxxx</Password>
            <Name>User's actual Name</Name>
            <Email>user's Reply Email</Email>
            <NotificationEmailAddress>user's Email</NotificationEmailAddress>
            <ActiveFlag>true</ActiveFlag>
            <IsAPIUser>false</IsAPIUser>
            <IsAPIUserSpecified>true</IsAPIUserSpecified>
            <IsLocked>false</IsLocked>
            <IsLockedSpecified>true</IsLockedSpecified>
            <MustChangePassword>true</MustChangePassword>
            <MustChangePasswordSpecified>true</MustChangePasswordSpecified>
            <DefaultBusinessUnit>MID</DefaultBusinessUnit>
            <SsoIdentities>
               <SsoIdentity>
                  <Client>
                     <ID>MID</ID>
                  </Client>
                  <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                  <FederatedID>user's ID</FederatedID>
               </SsoIdentity>
            </SsoIdentities>
            <Roles>
               <Role>
                  <ObjectID>role GUID</ObjectID>
               </Role>
            </Roles>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
   </soap:Body>
```